# Cannot I check the existance through "file:///……" in node.js?

Tags: node.js

If I have a file whose path is `c:\\a.txt`. And when I wrote the code below:

```js
let isExist = require('fs').existsSync('c:/a.txt');  //This returns me true
```

However if I wrote this:

```js
let isExist = require('fs').existsSync('file:///c:/a.txt');  //This returns me false
```

Cannot I use existsSync to check the path starting with "file:///" in the node.js? why? Any reasons or explainations to that?

Comment: what happens if you do `'file:\\\\c:\\a.txt'`

Comment: Belows are all false:

1. file:\\\\c:\\a.txt
2. file://c:/a.txt
3. file:///c:/a.txt

Comment: I think having the file:/// before the path is URL notation, used by web browsers and such. I don't think it's used in file systems but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine with me:

```js
let isExist = require('fs').existsSync(new URL('file:///c:/a.txt'));
```

It seems I MUST use "URL" to surround it, though I don't know why....